# Bluetooth Serial Data Transfer Hangs at same points

Tags: java, bluetooth, serial-port, arduino, serial-communication

I am to transfer two files from a Java app to an Arduino of roughly 200k each to be saved to uSD. With a USB connection this is going fine using the RXTX library and simple data parsing on the Arduino. I now want to replace the USB connect with a bluetooth using a HC-06 module.

Without changing anything the transfer works but it takes 12 minutes rather than 2 minutes. The transfer hangs at the same 4 (maybe 50) points of the transfer, seen by percentage progress.

The bottleneck must be in the RXTX library or bluteooth TX but can't find what's happening. Is there anything I can tweak or is this a limitation of a basic bluetooth module?

Here are snippets from code FWIW, nothing out of the ordinary (I think!) :

Java :

```
    int perc = data.length / 100;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < data.length ; i++) {
        try{
            output.write(data[i]);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }
        if(i % perc == 0) System.out.println(i / perc);
    }
```

Arduino :

```
boolean waiting = true;
while( lastData + 2000 > millis() || waiting){
    while(Serial.available()) {
        waiting = false;

        if(Serial.available() >= 255) nodes[nodeCount++] = byteCount;

        buff[bytInc++] = Serial.read();
        if(bytInc == 512) {             
            bytInc = 0;
            in.write(buff,512); 
        }
        lastData = millis();
        byteCount++;    
    }

}
in.write(buff,bytInc);
in.flush();
```

Any optimisation in the snippets above would be much appreciated. The baud rate is 38400. Any faster and the buffer overloads when writing to uSD. 
Arduino board is a Mega with 256 byte serial buffer.

Much appreciated. Have hunted about for relevant posts but can't find anything on bluetooth file transfers like this.

Comment: It also takes exactly (to second exact) the same time to transfer each time, 786 seconds...

Comment: try adding output.flush() every tot % on the java side. Can you measure every how much byte you get the code hungs? if it is every 512 byte then it is the in.write witch is blocking, you can try to check if there is a asincronous write

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Added output.flush() every percent and it solved the hanging up. however it still seems just as slow if not slower. In fact on both attempts it didn't finish as the serial read while loop timed out, meaning a whole second went without receiving data. 
Where is the holdup here? This is running off a macbook pro, is it possible it is buffering packets to send to the BT module? 
Am going to see if it transfers any differently in windows VM, but this seems to be an issue/restriction outside of my code.

Comment: every compenent has it's buffer. with flush you are forcing to empty the buffer on the PC side, but ssems like DT module has it's own buffer. Tecnically BT module is transparent to PC BUT maybe it give some way to force flush, using a non-serial-standard call. But RXTX is old. ifactc even the arduino from the newest versione (1.5.6) use another lib. try it!